# How to format sfChart DateTimeAxis Label Style so that it contains only capitalized words

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion, letters, capitalize

I am using SyncFusion for graphics. For that purpose, I am specifically using SfChart component. In this component, I want to be able to format dates as following:

MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN (That means that show only days with capital letters)

To do so, I played with LabelFormat property of ChartAxisLabelStyle in sfChart:

```
<chart:DateTimeAxis.LabelStyle>
      <chart:ChartAxisLabelStyle x:Name="DateAxisLabelStyle" TextColor="{StaticResource HistogramChartAxisLabelColorTheme1}">
        <chart:ChartAxisLabelStyle.LabelFormat>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="EEE" WinPhone="ddd" Android="EEE" />
        </chart:ChartAxisLabelStyle.LabelFormat>
      </chart:ChartAxisLabelStyle>
    </chart:DateTimeAxis.LabelStyle>
```

Also, I tried to write converters, but none of them did not work.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Thanks :)